# Get selected value from label/Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

I need help in getting selected value either from data-table(Jquery plugin) cell or from a label, below I have attached a file which will help to understand the requirements.

I was looking for Jquery plugin to implement this, but I couldn't find much.

Help would be appreciated. :)

[image: https://ufile.io/nvmci]

Comment: With over 2k rep you should know that asking for library recommendations are off topic and also why you tagged C# is a mystery.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the suggestion, I have modified the tags. I am looking for a plugin which can help me to achieve this functionality. Please Suggest if you are aware of it. Thank you.

Comment: You're looking for a plugin which is a software library, that's why your question is off topic here.

Comment: @DavidG Looking for javascript library, its a language, not a software.

Comment: Yes, Javascript is still software...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got a solution for the given issue.

Javascript itself provides functionality to get the selected value from the document
by using `window.getSelection();` or `document.getSelection();`

What I have tried and it works for me.

```
if (!window.x) {
    x = {};
}

x.Selector = {};
x.Selector.getSelected = function() {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
        var mytext = x.Selector.getSelected();
        alert(mytext);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YstZn/1/